# cURL follow .ASP Link gets 404

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, libcurl

I have the following small cURL PHP Script which has to follow an ASP link:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=<ID>&site=14910&type=text&tnb=2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie_jar.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie_jar.txt');  
$page= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But I only get:

```
The requested URL /click4.aspx was not found on this server.
```

Has anybody got an idea as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Fiddler is your friend.](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: hmm... i had a look a fiddler. its of course really expensive. And i'm not sure how to handle it. Seems to be really difficult?

Comment: Fiddler is 100% free and extremely easy to use. Install it, run it, see what your HTTP requests are actually doing. I consider it a mandatory tool for any sort of web development.

Comment: So i have tracked the redirects, not with fiddler, but with a "Tamper" Plugin for Firefox and get the following result of redirects:

http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.aspx?ref=<ID>&site=<ID2>&type=text&tnb=2
http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click3.aspx?ref=<ID>&site=<ID2>&type=text&tnb=2
http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click4.aspx?ref=<ID>&site=<ID2>&type=text&tnb=2
http://track.tnm.de/wa/ad?cid=<dynamicID>&ref=<ID>&affmt=2&affmn=2
http://www.mrssporty.de/?RefID=A_a_<ID>

How can i go through all these Links, collect the Cookies, and than work with the final URL ?